# Linux display ipaddres before logon

Tags: linux, authentication, prompt

We build software running on Linux servers (Centos)

We don't want the customer to have access to the Linux server, but the customer sometimes need to know the ipaddress of the server.

So my question is: Is it possible to display the ipaddress at the loginscreen (no graphical interface), that means, before the user has logged in?

Michael

Comment: How would they connect to it, if they don't have the address?

Comment: Ahh, I forgot to give that information: They have the server locally, and would look at the screen attached to the server.

Comment: Can you not just label the cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.  If you're talking about a text console, then you just need to create a shell script that executes this command:

```
/usr/bin/watch -n 60 /sbin/ifconfig > /dev/tty2
```

Then change `/etc/inittab` so that it runs that shell script on `tty2` instead of `getty`.  The user then just has to switch to `tty2` with <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> to see the network settings, including IP address.

You can also do it if you have a graphical X login, but it's a little more work.

Comment: Fantastic, just what we needed :-)